# How to launch new window below current window using xulrunner

Tags: linux, xul, fedora, gnome, xulrunner

I have situation that I'm calling mplayer every *x* minutes from xulrunner application and it always gets focus and comes on top, in front of other windows. But I need it to be behind xulrunner which has transparent box in which video should be visible.

Is there some way to force new process (mplayer) to be behind oldier process (xulrunner) and not to get autofocus on it?

Is it a Linux window manager level or there's some property in xulrunner or mplayer? (I'm using Fedora 18 with Openbox)

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be achieved using [devilspie](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/).  This tool allows you to customize many properties of application's windows including their focus, decoration, placement, and geometry.  There is a handy frontend for it called [gdevilspie](http://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/), though there are no rpms available so it must be installed from source.

You can set devilsiie to match on all mplayer windows and set their action to "below" which will place them below all normal windows.  Unfortunately this will apply to all invocations of mplayer, so this solution may be annoying if you use mplayer under other circumstances.